# Wifi connection is constantly lost

Tags: wireless, asus

I have Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. 
For some reason - I don't exactly know which one - my wifi module doesn't work. So, I bought an external wifi module ASUS USB-N13.

I've installed all required drivers, but I still have to run this command on every system startup to make this adapter work:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
```

If I don't run this command in the network utility at the top of the desktop I see that wifi is disabled by hardware switch. So, I run this command to make adapter work.

And here's the question: after some time(may be 5-10 mins) connection is lost. I still can see all wifi networks enabled, but when I try to connect back to my home network password window appeared. When I enter my password windows disappears and in a minute it appears again. The password I'm enter is surely right. So, I have to unplug usb adapter and plug it again and after it wifi start works in normal mode for 5 or 10 mins and after it everything is back.
Any ideas how I could solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
```

The command removes these modules from the Linux Kernel

```
b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
```

You can blacklist them so that when you boot these modules are not loaded anymore.

For that open the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf using vim

```
vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and insert these lines at the end of this file by pressing i (for insertion mode)

```
blacklist b43
blacklist ssb
blacklist wl
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
```

save and quit the file by pressing :wq followed by a enter

Reboot your pc and you should be using your wireless network without any kind of problem.

Comment: ,thx for your reply!
But how can the problem of constant connection lost be connected with deleting this modules on startup instead of manual deletion them after system loads?
Thanks.